# how to add content to html.label in javascript asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a label as 
<%= Html.Label("");%>
i want to add content to  label  at runtime, unfortunately it doesn't take any other parameter to create id property for it. can't i create id property for it just similar to asp:label

thanks,

michaeld

Answer (score 2):

No need to use the HtmlHelper functions always and everywhere if they don't fit your need. They're just supposed to make your life easier, not harder. Use good ole HTML here:

```
<label id="id_for_label"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using HtmlHelper functions you can always create your own extension methods.

For example:

```
public static class LabelHelper
{
    private static string HtmlAttributes(object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in 
            TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(htmlAttributes))
        {
            builder.AppendFormat(" {0}=\"{1}\" ", descriptor.Name, 
                descriptor.GetValue(htmlAttributes));
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString MyLabel(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
        string labelText, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var attributes = HtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(
            String.Format("<label for=\"{0}\" {1}>{0}</label", 
            labelText, attributes.Trim()));
    }
}
```

Then you can add a label to a view in the following manner:

```
<%: Html.MyLabel("Hello, World!", new { @id = "myLabel" })%>
```

The generated HTML is:

```
<label for="Hello, World!" id="myLabel">Hello, World!</label>
```

For MVC 3 such a helper function is already available:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg538318(v=VS.99).aspx